# Problem with running multiple Websites on Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS with Apache

Tags: networking, apache-virtualhost

I am new to Linux networking. I set up an Ubuntu Server and I use my laptop as a client via `SSH`. I am trying to host 2 websites on the server but when I test the web pages on my Laptop, they will never open.

This is the first website `/etc/apache2/sites-available/gbctestsite.com.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName gbctestsite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/gbctestsite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is the second website `/etc/apache2/sites-available/olasunkanmi123.com.conf` :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName olasunkanmi123.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/olasunkanmi123.com
</VirtualHost>
```

My laptop is on the same local network with the server. When I type `gbctestsite.com` and `olasunkanmi123.com` on my laptop's chrome browser address bar, I get

> (website name)'s server IP address could not be found

and `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` error message for both websites.

The Apache's default page opens on any device on my network but the other two sites will not.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! [Please don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Instead, paste the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: Did you register the DNS names?

Comment: No I haven't. Where can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the DNS names. Here are some ways to do it.

- Add to `/etc/hosts` — only accessible from same machine, ok for testing site in development.
- Register a name on https://freedns.afraid.org/ for free — You won't get a nice name, but good for testing, and if you don't need a nice name.
- Pay some money: buy a name and register it.

I would do them in that order. Even if you want the latter, to them in order (no need to progress, until you have something working).

Also if you are on a home ISP, then you need to check that you have at least one public IP address. And that your router can forward to it. This will not matter if testing, or connecting from within the LAN, but will matter when you connect to the public internet. You will also benefit from setting up a script to update DNS registration (as your IP address may change).

However I repeat. Do one thing at a time. 
 - First set up `/etc/hosts`, that way you can get the web server working.

Use `getent ahosts domain-name-of-server` to test the name look up. If this test passes. Then you have this bit done.

Comment: I will go with the no 1 for the moment, though I have a registered domain I would like to use for the option 2 later. Presently, these are the entries I have in my '/etc/hosts' file: '127.0.0.1 localhost' and '127.0.1.1 ubuntu_server'. ubuntu_server is my server name. What entry can I add so that I can test the website with 'gbctestsite.com'?

Comment: Extend the entry to `127.0.0.1 localhost gbctestsite.com`, be where that if this name exists (out on the internet) then you will no longer be able to access it.You will instead access your machine.

Comment: I did as you said but no changes. I am trying to access the websites from my laptop which is connected to my server through SSH. Could this be the problem? My server doesn't have a GUI therefore I can't run a browser on it for the testing!

Comment: Yes. Add edit the `/etc/hosts` on the laptop (the machine that needs to know). And are you connecting to the web-site via `ssh`?

Comment: My laptop is on Ubuntu 20.04 and I am using it to connect to the server via `SSH`. I test the websites on Chrome on the laptop. I have been on this today for hours trying to play with the settings but I am getting new error code `ERR-CONNECTION_REFUSED` instead of `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` I previously get. I have no clue of what to do next!

Comment: Use `getent ahosts domain-name-of-server` to test the name look up. If this test passes. Then you have this bit done. Accept the answer, and ask another question.

Comment: IT'S FINALLY WORKING. As @ctrl-alt-delor suggested, I added `127.0.0.1 olasunkanmi123.com` to my server's `/etc/hosts` and `my_server_static_ip_address olasunkanmi123.com` to my laptop's `/etc/hosts` . By that, I am able to test the websites on my laptop.